# How do I turn off the tap?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

In world 1-3 of Paper Mario: Sticker Star, there is a tap you need to turn off in order to get the comet sticker.

I have no idea how to turn this off, and if I ask Kersti for help, she just says "What's that strange thing up there?"

I don't see any strange things, or a way to place a sticker or anything helpful.

How do I turn off the tap?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jump on faucet head a few times to turn off the water. Then jump back into the hole the sticker fell in and you'll notice that the water filled path is now gone.